# Scala has dynamic compilation?

Tags: scala, dynamic, groovy, compilation

I have found many pages saying scala doesn't have the dynamic compilation feature, whereas I have achieved the same using [twitter util library](https://github.com/twitter/util). I wrote a scala code calling `Eval` function from mentioned lib and it create a scala class at runtime.

```
example val obj = Eval[MyScalaTrait](new File("flat file having scala code")))
```

Can you please tell me for dynamic compilation which one is better scala or groovy. I want to keep scripting part in a `flat file` and at run time create class. Looks like both are solving my problem, but want to see which would would be best?

Comment: better for what? why don't try both approaches and measure them with a metric, that defines "better" for your usecase?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you about Groovy, but I'm using dynamic compilation of Scala code in several projects. It works mostly flawlessly, but the compiler may take it bit of warm-up time, so don't expect this to give you fantastic low latencies in "real-time" situations.

Comment: Thanks, are you also using same twitter util lib, or some thing else?  I agree dynamic compilation would take some time, can I ask you, how is the performance of your application with dynamic compilation and why to choose scala for dynamic compilation, i believe you must have also explored other options.

Comment: I am just using `IMain`, the main compiler instance. I am using on the one hand [a wrapper library](https://github.com/Sciss/ScalaInterpreterPane) that is more like the REPL, but also an "oblivious" [compiler instance](https://github.com/Sciss/SoundProcesses/blob/master/compiler/src/main/scala/de/sciss/synth/proc/impl/CompilerImpl.scala).